# Expose RAML contract instead WADL in CXF

Tags: rest, cxf, wadl, cxfrs, raml

I am new in REST world, an in most of CXF examples that I saw there is an configuration to expose WADL in REST services when published.

Something like

```
Available RESTful services:
Endpoint address: http://localhost:8080/ouat-servicesImpl/api
WADL : http://localhost:8080/ouat-servicesImpl/api?_wadl
```

Then, when clicked

```
<application>
  <grammars/>
  <resources base="http://localhost:8080/ouat-servicesImpl/api">
    <resource path="/topics">
      <method name="POST">
        <request>
          <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </request>
        <response>
          <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
      </method>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</application>
```

I was learning RAML and its benefits in contract creation. Is there any way to expose RAML contract in this CXF "home" service page? Or am I mixing the concepts/ purpose of RAML and WADL? Actually I think both are ways to expose services contract, however in my opinion RAML is more complete

Comment: Both describes the contract. But RAML is getting popular these days. WADL was a failure as I know.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am hearing. Do you know if there is some way to expose this RAML contract when the service is expose with CXF?

Comment: You can expose your RAML file with an URL, just like WSDL.  You can also take a look at at swagger, which also supports RAML. Swagger provides a UI to discover, document and test your REST endpoints.

Comment: "however in my opinion RAML is more complete"

Actually, RAML is less complete *BY DESIGN*.  RAML was intentionally created to specify "practically" RESTful designs because in reality almost nobody who is doing "REST" is actually doing REST.  If RAML could only specify actually RESTful services, nobody would be able to adopt it for existing projects.  This isn't meant to be a dig at RAML, the authors explain all this in the documentation.  It was a carefully considered design decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you package your CXF service as a WAR, here is how you can achieve your goal, based on a real project I'm working on:

- Drop RAML and JSON files below the webroot folder: https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/tree/master/webapp/src/main/webapp/raml
- Template `baseUri` so it can be injected at runtime: https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/blob/master/webapp/src/main/webapp/raml/api_v1.raml#L21
- Declare `.raml` as if it's a JSP so injection can work: https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/blob/master/webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L70
- Add the RAML mime-type: https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/blob/master/webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L76-L79
- Add a filter to compute the dynamic part of the `baseUri`: https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/blob/master/webapp/src/main/java/eu/openanalytics/rpooli/web/BaseUriInjectionFilter.java
- Wire it in web.xml: https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/blob/master/webapp/src/main/java/eu/openanalytics/rpooli/web/BaseUriInjectionFilter.java

Bonus point for:

- Embedding the RAML API console: https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/tree/master/webapp/src/main/webapp/raml/ui
- And redirecting to it from the web-app home page: https://github.com/openanalytics/RPooli/blob/master/webapp/src/main/webapp/index.html